# How To Use Controller For Novay WordTemplate Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

In Laravel I use Novay WordTemplate to generate a generated word template.
I took the code from github https://github.com/novay/laravel-word-template.
But I have a problem when I want to move the function to the Controller.

I move in the following way:

On my Route fill like this:

```
Route::get('/word', [WordController::class, 'word'])->name('word');
```

Then in the controller I made it like this:

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Novay\WordTemplate\Facade;
  
class WordController extends Controller
{     
    public function word()
    {
        $file = public_path('surat_pernyataan.rtf');
    
        $array = array(
            '[NOMOR_SURAT]' => '015/BT/SK/V/2017',
            '[PERUSAHAAN]' => 'Bea Cukai Bekasi',
            '[NAMA]' => 'Melani Malik',
            '[NIP]' => '6472065508XXXX',
            '[ALAMAT]' => 'Jl. Manunggal Gg. 8 Loa Bakung, Samarinda',
            '[PERMOHONAN]' => 'Permohonan pengurusan pembuatan NPWP',
            '[KOTA]' => 'Samarinda',
            '[DIRECTOR]' => 'Noviyanto Rahmadi',
            '[TANGGAL]' => date('d F Y'),
        );

        $nama_file = 'surat-keterangan-kerja.doc';
        
        return WordTemplate::export($file, $array, $nama_file);
    }
}
```

But got error : Class "App\Http\Controllers\WordTemplate" not found. Please help me solve

Comment: What you tried to change the name of the import to `WordTemplate`? `use Novay\WordTemplate\Facade as WordTemplate`

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to solve the problem. But I got into trouble again when the app was uploaded on the host with a separate public_html from the app. How to handle it?

I would be very grateful if you could address my problem.

the error is : file_get_contents(/home/mywebsite/laravel/public/surat_pernyataan.rtf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory